# Passing pointer to an array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a test function that takes an array as an argument. And I have an array of pointers. Can someone explain why I need to deference the pointer to an array of pointers when I pass it?

```
void test(States a[]){

    cout << a[0].name << endl;
    cout << a[1].name << endl;
}
```

Calling `test()`:

```
States *pStates[MAX_STATES];
test(*pStates); //Or test(pStates[0])
                //Can't do test(pStates);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't need to dereference if the arguments of test function expect so

```
void test(States *a[]);
```

But in your case, clearly the argument type is `States []`, so you need to pass a pointer.

You may want to consider rewriting test function as:

```
void test(States *a[]){
    cout << a[0]->name << endl;
    cout << a[1]->name << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This wasn't exactly the explanation I was looking for. I figured it out, `pStates` is a pointer to a pointer to an object and by passing that to a function that accepts an array, I need to dereference `pStates` to get a pointer to an object. From there it's just pointer arithmetic using array indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
void test(States* a[]){

    cout << a[0]->name << endl;
    cout << a[1]->name << endl;
}
```

And you won't need to dereference it...

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of `pStates` declares an array of pointers. Not a pointer to an array.
However the function `void test(States a[]);` expects an array of objects (`States` objects).

You can't just cast one to the other.

```
#include <iostream>

typedef struct {
    int name;
} States; //Surely this should be called State (not plural)

const size_t MAX_STATES=2;


void test(States a[]){
    std::cout << a[0].name << std::endl;
    std::cout << a[1].name << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    
    States lFirst;
    States lSecond;
    lFirst.name=1;
    lSecond.name=7;
    
    
    //Here's what you had. 
    States*pStates[MAX_STATES];
    
    //Now initialise it to point to some valid objects.
    pStates[0]=&lFirst;
    pStates[1]=&lSecond;
    
    //Here's what you need to do.
    States lTempStates[]={*pStates[0],*pStates[1]};

    test(lTempStates); 
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```